# Failed to create job with prefix beam_bq_job_LOAD while writing to bigquery Apache Beam dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

When I run my pipeline that writes data to bigquery, I got this error:

```
Error message from worker: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create job with prefix beam_bq_job_LOAD_campaignprocessinguser10311348175a423790_5ed64e7c6f85472190b06e6791e16333_55b5a9b937ae9d5800e61ae94bab532c_00001_00000, reached max retries: 3, last failed job: null.
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryHelpers$PendingJob.runJob(BigQueryHelpers.java:200)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryHelpers$PendingJobManager.waitForDone(BigQueryHelpers.java:153)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables$WriteTablesDoFn.finishBundle(WriteTables.java:378)
```

Comment: Was it the only exception shown in the logs? I believe this error just confirms that there's a failure and retrying didn't solve. It is supposed to have another section for the cause. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes it is the only exception in the logs @BrunoVolpato

Comment: Interesting. Does the service account being used have permissions to create jobs on BigQuery? Do other methods (streaming inserts, storage write) work fine?

Comment: It does I have already checked it @BrunoVolpato

Comment: The message says it failed to create the job, but can you check if there is any job footprint on BigQuery, just to make sure? Can usually be accessed on BigQuery UI -> Project History.

Comment: Can you check of you have other error in `Dataflow` log, for example `job log` and stastitics ? You had a failure in the instantation of your job.

Comment: I believe that the error is in the schema writing to bigquery, since the error was not seen before updating the schema

Comment: Can you follow this [document](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#creating-a-table-schema) to create table schema and write data to table?

Comment: I had a similar error message and it turned out it was due to an invalid schema. Can you show how you create your schema?